# Firebase Authentication with Rest API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm stuck with Firebase Autentication.

I understand how to connect my single page app to FireAuth. 
But then, I'm lost.

I don't know how to automatically inform my rest api that a new user is create.

Because if a new user select the login page and click on Google login provider, there is no rule to inform the user he must sign-up first.

Comment: If the new account was created, the user is also signed in. In the callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's account data.

Comment: It was obvious ! Thank you.

Comment: Good. I have created an answer, please feel free to accept to resolve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the new account was created, the user is also signed in. In the callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's account data.